# HTML Form Submission with JQuery in a Django Application

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I use the following pieces of HTML and JQuery code to navigate pages in a website (I am also using Django; hence, the double curly braces). My code works fine only in Safari, but not in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera, even though it seems logically and syntactically correct. Any ideas why it doesn't work? Thank you for your help in advance.

Some more information: I am using the Django development server for now. My OS is macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

```
<form id="myform" action="..." method="get">
    <a class="pg-nav" data-nav-value="-1" href="">Previous</a>
    <span id="pg-cur">{{ pageNumber }} / {{ totalNumPages }}</span>
    <a class="pg-nav" data-nav-value="1" href="">Next</a>

    <input id="pg" type="hidden" name="pg" value="0">
</form>


$('.pg-nav').click(function() {
    var curPage = parseInt($('#pg-cur').text());
    var navVal = parseInt($(this).data('nav-value'));
    var newVal = curPage + navVal;
    $('#pg').val(newVal);
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Comment: When you say it **doesn't work** - does that mean "submits the form but with the wrong values", "does not submit the form", "submits the form but the server doesn't seem to give the right results" or something else? If the form is not submitted, do you see any browser console errors?

Comment: Great question. I should have explained what happens. In Firefox, the same page is reloaded. In other words, the value of the pg input does not get changed. It remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links still try to reload the page because you allow the default behaviour of the `a` tag to be processed. You can prevent it using the [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method:

```
$('.pg-nav').click(function(e) {
    ...
    $('#myform').submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```